# Get rid of index.php/ on codeigniter

Tags: php, .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I have this in my `.htaccess` file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>    
Options +FollowSymLinks     
Options -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On    
RewriteBase /   
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d     
RewriteRule ^.+$ /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

My website shows the file inside `index.php` for all my webfiles. I'm trying to get rid of having to put in the `mysite/index.php/filename` and go directly to `mysite/filename`

My website address is `http://local-news.today/subscribe`. It works when I used this address `local-news.today/index.php/subscribe` it shows what's on the subscribe function.

My website is hosted in godaddy. I'm using codeigniter too. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Make sure you have `$config['index_page'] = ''` in `config.php`.

Comment: Yes mine is already set to that.

Answer (score 1):

I've done the following in my htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

This works for me.

Answer (score 1):

put following code in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L,QSA]
```

and in application/config/config.php find the following line

```
$config['index_page'] = "index.php"
```

and replace it with following code

```
$config['index_page'] = ""
```

Comment: local-news.today/subscribe/ gives me "No input file specified." blank page. Get the same result when I try to make up some invalid directory.

Comment: Can you please explain the issue ?

Answer (score 1):

A simple search for "codeigniter mod_rewrite htaccess" showed me [this gist](https://gist.github.com/philipptempel/4226750):

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  # !IMPORTANT! Set your RewriteBase here and don't forget trailing and leading
  #  slashes.
  # If your page resides at
  #  http://www.example.com/mypage/test1
  # then use
  # RewriteBase /mypage/test1/
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
  # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
  # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.
  # Submitted by: ElliotHaughin

  ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```

So basically your rewrite rule is a bit wrong. You need something like

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
```

What does this mean?
`^(.*)$` maches everything (`(.*)`) from the beginning (`^`) to the end (`$`) and appends it using `$1` to *index.php?/*

In your example you forgot to append it to the end of the url...

Answer (score 1):

In my experience, on shared hosting you often have to play around with the `.htaccess` file. This one usually works for me:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt|static) [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/?$1 [L,QSA]
```

But you will notice that the last line here differs from the other answers, with the `?` coming *after* the `/` rather than before it (or not at all). So try this as a base `.htaccess`, then modify the final line if necessary. It may also be necessary to remove the `RewriteBase \` line.

Answer (score 1):

I always use this one and it works like a charm:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /

    #Removes access to the system folder by users.
    #Additionally this will allow you to create a System.php controller,
    #previously this would not have been possible.
    #'system' can be replaced if you have renamed your system folder.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^system.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #When your application folder isn't in the system folder
    #This snippet prevents user access to the application folder
    #Rename 'application' to your applications folder name.
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^application.*
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

    #Checks to see if the user is attempting to access a valid file,
    #such as an image or css document, if this isn't true it sends the
    #request to index.php
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>

<IfModule !mod_rewrite.c>
    # If we don't have mod_rewrite installed, all 404's
    # can be sent to index.php, and everything works as normal.

    ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
</IfModule>
```